# Find and replace, but not if near a letter or number

Tags: bash, sed, replace

With `sed`, I can replace one item with another. E.g.:

```
sed -i "s/a/b/g" file
```

However, there are times when I do not want this replacement to happen. How can I ensure that the replacement only happens when:

- The character immediately before is not a letter, number, or `{`.
- The character immediately after is not a letters or number, or `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r -e "s/([^0-9a-zA-Z\{])a([^0-9a-zA-Z\}])/\1b\2/g"
```

`([^0-9a-zA-Z\{])` - is a first matched group of symbols (length of 1 in current case). Not a number (`0-9`), not a letter (`a-zA-Z`) and not a { (`\{`).

`([^0-9a-zA-Z\}])` - is a second matched group, just like first.

If we matched those sequences, we substitute it with first group (`\1`), `b` and second group (`\2`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
% echo '2a: {a} a cat.' | sed -e 's/\([^{[:alnum:]]\)a\([^}[:alnum:]]\)/\1b\2/g'
2a: {a} b cat.
```

The `\(...\)` form groups, which are stored and used in the substitution, refered to with `\1`, `\2`, ...`\9`.